# Speeding up deleting of columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this formula to delete empty columns in my sheet. But it takes around 15-20min to delete them. Can I somehow speed up this proces? It's weird that it takes so long and I'm only working with 100 columns.

```
For j = 1 To 5
    For i = 40 To 146
        If Sheet8.cells(4, i) = "" Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: What is the For loop over j doing? I assume nothing, so that is the first step. Remove that loop. Second step, IMO you need to delete the columns backwards, i.e. `For i = 146 To 40 Step -1`

Comment: @EnnaSmile why do you use 2 loops?

Comment: @Storax if I just use loop i, then it doesn't shift the columns enough since sometimes I have more than one empty column between.

Comment: That's the reason why you need to go backwards

Comment: @ALOXAZ same answer as for Storax

Comment: @Storax okay, thanks for the help.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you have **real bank cells** use [@Patrick Honorez answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52888045/3219613)  using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` which is faster.

But if you have **no real blank cells** (eg formulas that show as `""`) then you can use this:

```
Dim DeleteRange As Range

With sheet8
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 40 To 146
        If .Cells(4, i).Value = vbNullString Then 'vbNullString = ""
            If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRange = .Columns(i)
            Else
                Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, .Columns(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then 'check if there is something to delete
    DeleteRange.EntireColumn.Delete
End If
```

It collects all columns that you want to delete in `DeleteRange` and then deletes them at once. This is faster than deleting each column on its own, because each delete action needs its time (and here we have only one delete action).

Note that we don't need to loop backwards here because we only collect the columns within the loop but delete action comes **after** the loop, so it doesn't affect the loop counting at all.

Comment: His one is the fastest one for now.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
For i = 146 To 40 step -1
    If Sheet8.cells(4, i) = "" Then
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adjusting this for your needs. I think nothing can go faster :-)

```
Sub test()
    Range("C3:j17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this only works on real blank cells. If there are cells containing formulas that show up as blanks you should use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52888117/3219613). For real blank cells this is definitely the fastest solution here.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do it like that.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TurnOffFunctionality()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
Private Sub TurnOnFunctionality()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub TestIt()

Dim i As Long

    TurnOffFunctionality

    For i = 146 To 40 Step -1
        If Sheet8.Cells(4, i) = "" Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    TurnOnFunctionality

End Sub
```

Turning off especially re-calculation will make sure that a re-caculation is not triggered with every deletion of a single column in the loop. This could probably be the cause of the long run time.

Comment: For your interest: Collecting the columns with `Union` and delete them all at once is even faster than deleting each column on its own. Even if you turn everything off.

Comment: Yes, right. Turning off everything is just the first thought you have in such a case. Even with your solution I would turn off everything though it will not be faster. It is just as a behaviour maybe even Cargo Cult :-)

Comment: Actually turning things off if you don't need to makes it slower (theoretically at least, didn't test if measurable at all). Turning things off/on also takes time ;) And even worse code gets complicated for no reason. Cannot sign that.

Comment: As I said, maybe Cargo-Cult. But in cases code accesses the workbook events are triggered and re-calculation might run. For such cases I would re-commend to do that. For your solution above it is not neccessary even superfluous and might also slow down the code.

Comment: Of course for this solution here I would totally sign to turn everything off.

Comment: And my lesson learned form this discussion: Just do not turn off everything blindly. Think before if it's really neccessary otherwise it's just cargo-cult ;-)

Comment: I'd add that if you want to turn calculation off you may as well remember what it was beforehand rather than blindly turning it back to `xlCalculationAutomatic`.  Something like `Calc = Application.Calculation: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: Rest of Code.... :Application.Calculation = Calc`